# Where did i find my rtmp server link?

Tags: flash-builder, rtmp

I am going to implement an live video chat on my site, i have an BroadcastInterface.swf file, which needs the `connection string` to the `RTMP` server.

> I have embeded that swf file to my site as shown in following html
>   code...

```
<object classid="clsid:d27cdb6e-ae6d-11cf-96b8-444553540000" codebase="http://download.macromedia.com/pub/shockwave/cabs/flash/swflash.cab#version=6,0,29,0" width="720" height="500">
              <PARAM NAME=FlashVars VALUE="&tepercentage=<? echo $epercentage;?>&fuser=<? echo $sUser; ?>&fcpm=<? echo $nCpm; ?>&fid=<? echo $sId; ?>&fmoney=<? echo $nMoney; ?>&connection=<? echo $connection_string;?>"  />
              <param name="quality" value="high"  />
              <param name="movie" value="BroadcastInterface.swf"  />
              <embed flashvars="&tepercentage=<? echo $epercentage;?>&fuser=<? echo $sUser; ?>&fcpm=<? echo $nCpm; ?>&fid=<? echo $sId; ?>&fmoney=<? echo $nMoney; ?>&connection=<? echo $connection_string;?>" src="BroadcastInterface.swf" quality="high" pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="720" height="500">
              </embed>
            </object>
```

So my question is only that where i can find my RTMP server link or is there need to sign up on any site to get RTMP server link? Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

You need to actually setup an RTMP server and configure it... or use a 3rd party service that will host the RTMP server for you.

[Adobe Media Server](http://www.adobe.com/products/adobe-media-server-family.html) (formerly known as Flash Media Server or FMS) is an expensive RTMP server from Adobe. The "professional" version is full featured and probably overkill for simple streaming applications. You used to be able to get a free "developers" license that was limited to 10 connections or something, I'm sure that's still available w/the newer version.

[Red 5](http://www.red5.org) is a free, open source RTMP server. Everyone else who didn't buy FMS is probably using this.

FMS and Red 5 are probably the most well known options. If you know Java and aren't put off by hosting your own server Red 5 is the way to go.

There are third parties that host RTMP servers. You can sign up with one of them rather than hosting your own server. In addition to these services, many cloud services providers (like Amazon) will let you create an FMS server in their cloud.

Comment: Thanks @Sunil D. for your reply...  Can you give me any link which provides the steps for creating third party RTMP server link...

Comment: There are a lot of of them, and I don't have any experience with any of them. You can find them with google search using the terms "rtmp server hosting". Good luck!